# XMLHttpRequest post multipart FormData, file gets added twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm making an upload mechanism using XMLHttpRequest and FormData. However when creating a request the file is somehow being added twice, what am I missing here?

I have a class `Uploader` being responsible for submitting a multipart form and a static object `cc` being responsible for the actual upload.

The `Uploader`-class's upload method is called from JS when the single input field dispatches the `change` event.

The `Uploader` class looks like the following:

```
class Uploader {
    constructor(form){
        this._form = form;
        this._files = [];
    }

    _buildFileIndex(){
        const fileInputsEl = this._form.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
        const fileInputs = Array.from(fileInputsEl).map(input => {
            return {
                'name': input.getAttribute('name') || 'undefined',
                'files': input.files
            }
        });

        this._fileInputs = fileInputs;
        return fileInputs;
    }

    _buildFormData(){
        this._formData = new FormData(this._form);
        for(let input of this._fileInputs){
            for(let file of input.files){
                this._formData.append(input.name, file, file.name);
            }
        }

        return this._formData;
    }

    upload(callback){
        this._buildFileIndex();
        this._buildFormData();

        cc.POST('/api/upload', this._formData, res => {
            if(typeof callback === 'function') callback(res);
        });
    }
}
```

The `cc` object:

```
const cc = {
    'serverADDR': function(){return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host},
    'POST': function(endpoint, data, callback, contentType){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('POST', cc.serverADDR() + endpoint, true);

        if(contentType) xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', contentType);

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if(typeof callback === 'function') callback(this);
            }
        };

        xhttp.send(data);
    }
}
```

And this is the data sent according to Google Chrome, when selecting only one file in one input:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryEDgRU4CNKJQjnIA8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="Skärmavbild 2017-10-29 kl. 12.16.50.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryEDgRU4CNKJQjnIA8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="Skärmavbild 2017-10-29 kl. 12.16.50.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryEDgRU4CNKJQjnIA8--
```

The submission of the form is made in a page-specific object `home`:

```
const home = {
    'el': {
        'inputs': {
            'form': document.querySelector('form'),
            'input': document.querySelector('input')
        }
    },
    'init': function(){
        home.setupForm();
    },
    'setupForm': function(){
        home.el.inputs.input.addEventListener('change', home.upload);
    },
    'upload': function(){
        const uploader = new Uploader(home.el.inputs.form);
        uploader.upload(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}

home.init();
```

...and the form itself is as simple as:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="file" name="media">
</form>
```

Comment: Hm, very strange. It keeps occurring, at first I thought it was a browser specific problem but it happens in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @Andreas to me it looks like it does happen even in your plunker. When looking at the request sent, two files are added even there.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about two requests... :|

Comment: `new FormData(this._form);` this creates a new `FormData` object with all input elements of the passed form. After that you add all input fields by hand -> 1 + 1 = 2

Comment: Ah, so it already adds the fields from the form when initializing the FormData instance?

Comment: Seems like I should've read the documentation a little more carefully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a FormData instance appends the fields of the provided form automatically. All files were therefore added twice before the request was sent.